# Windows URI Scheme for app installed for a user

Tags: windows, winforms, windows-installer, url-scheme

I have a desktop .net WinForms application which can be installed for everyone or for the current user.
The installer will also register the app as a URI scheme in HKCR.
This works as expected for all users but for the logged in user it's going to fail with permissions to the registry.

I could make this work and register the app for the given user but then the issue arrises when 2 people on the same machine install it.

Has anyone had this issue before and is there a elegant way to resolve it?
The easist way is to install the app for everyone but we have to give the option to install for just the logged in user.

I've search about and am struggling to find anyinfo if it's possible to have an entry per user.
One solution would be to create a launcher app which is installed for everyone and then call that which can check if it exists for the logged in user or for all.

Comment: HKCR by definition is HKey Current useR , not exactly sure what you're setting, typically user X may not set registry settings for user Y that would be a security breach. Usually installer accounts are used like administrators. If your not setting that much setting maybe use json config or so, in user\appdata file location.

Comment: No, HKCR is HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. HKCU is HKEY_CURRENT_USER also known as the per-user hive. HKCR is a strange key that merges views over per-machine and per-user. The problem as described by @Andy is a bit mysterious, but there isn't enough information to know for sure since the installation details are missing.

Comment: @RobMensching Thank you for your comment. I was trying to write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT which the user did not have permissions to.
I didn't know that HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT pulls from HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.
So redirecting my call to  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\<AppName> when installing for the user and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\ when in admin mode fixes the issue.

Comment: That explains that. I left an answer now that it is clear what you are doing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HKCR` (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT) is a special root that merges the per-machine `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and the per-user `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` into a single view. Reading works seamlessly. But if you want control over whether you are *writing* to the per-machine or per-user key, use the "real" registry path.